# jQuery events in $(window).load() block doesn't work after hosting on firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-hosting

1. I've deployed static website to firebase hosting. There is the page - https://sapcert-d5654.firebaseapp.com/sap-erp.html
2. There is script **filterContent.js**, linked to this page. There are two code blocks in this script: `$(document).ready(function () {...}` and `$(window).load(function() {...}`. Typing events (`.keyup()`) from `.ready()` block works fine, but click events (`.click()`) from `.load()` block don't work at all. Content of `.load()` block:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    console.log( "window loaded" );

    var navLinkSelector = "a.mdl-navigation__link";
    var subsolutionBlockSelector = ".subsolution-block";

    //Filtering by link click
    $(navLinkSelector).click(function(eventObject) {
        var currentLink = eventObject.target;
        var parent = $(currentLink).parent();
        var links = parent.children();
        var curLinkIdx = links.toArray().indexOf(currentLink);

        $.each(links, function (index, elem) {
            if (index != curLinkIdx) {
                $(elem).css("font-weight","normal");
            }
        });

        if ($(currentLink).attr("id") != "clearFilter") {
            if ($(currentLink).css("font-weight") != "bold") {
                $(currentLink).css("font-weight","bold");
            }

            $(subsolutionBlockSelector).each(function () {
                if ($(currentLink).text().search($(this).attr("title")) < 0) {
                    $(this).hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
            if ($("#clearFilter").css("display") == "none") {
                $("#clearFilter").show();
            }
        } else {
            $(subsolutionBlockSelector).show();
        }
        if ($(".mdl-layout__drawer").hasClass("is-visible")) {
            $(".mdl-layout").get(0).MaterialLayout.toggleDrawer();
        }
    });

    $("#clearFilter").click(function (eventObject) {
        eventObject.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).css("display") != "none") {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

3. But when I run website locally with `gulp serve:dist` all work fine.
4. When I host this website via google drive the problem is the same.

Comment: I have both console.log "document loaded" and "window loaded" in firefox.

Comment: which browser you are facing issue?

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked:  google apis   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: I use Chrome and Firefox. Yes, console.log works, but events for click doesn't.

Comment: @Lucas What this error means?

Comment: cross domain request is blocked by the server , you have to overcome it

Comment: if you console.log $('a.mdl-navigation__link').length inside the $(window).load(), you will see that the navigation link under Sub-solutions don't exists yet. Since, they are not in your HTML code, I guess you are loading it with a script and this a time issue (difference between the loading time on your local server and this server). Try to use delegation events, wait or add events after the links exist.

Comment: @progysm Yes, I load page content form JSON file by separate script with `$(document).ready(function () {...}` How to execute this script before *filterContent* script?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

it shows Cross-Origin Request Blocked: you may need to check https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors

Answer (score 0):

Great thanks to @progysm !!!

1. I've read this article - https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
2. Change event linking from children `$(navLinkSelector).click(function(eventObject) {...}` to it parent `$("#subsolutions-list").on("click", navLinkSelector, function(eventObject) {...}`
3. And it works now !!!